# Multi threading not working on python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to python and about to submit my project by tomorrow. I am developing a log monitoring system for ubuntu using python. I have designed a class for the log analysis. Now calling two thread and calling two instance of the class for monitoring more then 1 log at a time.

When i run the code first both of the thread run. But later only thread 2 run. Thread one is not.

Please tell me where should i make the changes to fix it? Or suggest any other muulti-threading system. Please just put a link reference of a function. I dont have much time to study on it. A small code correction will be very helpful.

```
 def start_thread(): 
  last_time=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
  global CheckVar1
  global CheckVar9
  CheckVar1 = 1
  CheckVar9 = 1
  mylist.insert(END,last_time+"            LOG MONITORING ACTIVATED.")
  #lock=thread.allocate_lock()

  thread.start_new_thread(_thread,("Thread No:1",1))
  thread.start_new_thread(_thread1,("Thread No:2",8))

 #------------------------------
 def _thread(string2,sleeptime,*args):
  #lock.acquire() 
  lineCount=0;
  check=0;
  print string2
  #mylist.insert(END,"checking,,,")
  #time.sleep(sleeptime);
  logic()

 def _thread1(string3,sleeptime2,*args):
  #lock.acquire() 
  lineCount=0;
  check=0;
  print string3
  #mylist.insert(END,"checking,,,")
  #time.sleep(sleeptime2);
  logic1()



 btn_start = Button(app, text = "GO >>")
 btn_start.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W);
 btn_start["command"]=start_thread



 class LogWatcher(object):
    def __init__(self, log_file_name, callback):
    self.log_file_name = log_file_name
    self.callback = callback
    global count_number_of_line
    print log_file_name
    self.initial_counting(log_file_name)



    def looping(self, waiting_time=5):
    while 1:
        self.check_change(self.log_file_name, count_number_of_line)
        print count_number_of_line
        time.sleep(waiting_time)




    def initial_counting(self, log_file_name):
    .....



    def check_change(self, log_file_name, last_count):
    .......



 def logic():    
        .....

    m=LogWatcher("/var/log/auth.log", callback)
    m.looping()

 def logic1():    

    ...
    l=LogWatcher("/var/log/kern.log", callback2)
    l.looping()
```

I didn't put the full code here. But if someone want it to run then you can download it from [here](http://www.ans4u.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/d.txt)

Comment: It'd be nice if you could make the effort to format your post correctly - your indentation is off

Comment: Do you want me to make the indentation correct on the code i upload or code i post? Because the code i upload it is perfect on that.

Comment: I have change the indentation please have a look.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site where you can get us to do your work
/homework. If you don't want to understand, what's the point. Look for another career.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't say that i dont want to understand. I study on multi-threading on google and put the code as it was in the document. But when i put the multi-threading for single function call it works. But when i put the multi-threading on nested function calling its not working. So i asked if anyone can pint where exactly i am doing the wrong. BTW one shouldn't need to feel the interest in all coding language. But in university they teach all language. So one may not feel interest in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the "standard" python implementation (aka cpython) you should be aware of the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). I quote (emphasis mine):

> In CPython, **the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at once**. This lock is necessary mainly because CPython's memory management is not thread-safe. (However, since the GIL exists, other features have grown to depend on the guarantees that it enforces.)

A possible alternative is to use actually use different processes using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. But in that case you'll have to explicitly send data to the other processes, since they don't share an address space. It might be advisable to start up the other processes before initializing the GUI.

Another point to keep in mind with regard to GUI toolkits like Tk is that it is usually only allowed to make Tk calls from the original thread.

Most GUI toolkits have timeout or idle functions that let you do small tasks when the GUI isn't doing anything. You could structure your app to use those.

Comment: thank you very much. i use the multiprocessing module and its now working.